# Using an AWS Lambda method to loop through a list and call multiple other lambda methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm currently calling an RDS DB to get a list of items, then I loop through these items to then make a POST call for each item. My question is:

Is it possible to loop through this list and call another Lambda function for each item in list. Ideally, this would not wait for a response but would continue calling the others. Each method called would continue running till they are completed. Please note this is based on NodeJs 6.10

Here is the structure:

```
  var pg = require('knex')({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    debug: true
  });

  // Internal
  const time = require('./lib/time');
  const response = require('./lib/response');
  const helpers = require('./lib/helpers');

  module.exports.createBatch = (event, context, cb) => {

    // Lambda settings
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    const now = time.getCurrentTime();

    pg('table')
      .join('table')
      .select('*')

      .then(function(rows) {
         return rows;
      })

      .then(function(rows) {
        console.log( 'rows: ' + rows );

        let count = 0;
        if (!_.isEmpty(rows)) {
          for(let row of rows) {

            // ****
            // CALL OTHER LAMBDA FUNCTION HERE
            // ****

            axios.post(row)
              .then(function (res) {

              // ****
              //  MOVE THIS POST CALL INTO ANOTHER LAMBDA FUNCTION
              // ****

              })

          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: the aws-sdk exposes a lambda invoke method

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the AWS SDK for Nodejs to call the Lambda [invoke()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) function. Pass the `InvocationType: Event` parameter to invoke the function asynchronously without waiting for a response.

Comment: It's worth pointing out: you will quickly hit your concurrent execution limit and that total throughput of doing a lot of invokes like this suffers unless you use an HTTP KeepAlive agent passed in via (new AWS.Lambda({ httpOptions })

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using 'lambda.invoke'. Please see more details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) about invoke